# Google Place API Status gives NULL if use Proguard

Tags: android, google-maps, proguard, google-places-api

I have downloaded [**Google Maps and Place API**](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/) Example from AndroidHive, I have implemented this code with my Google API Key and Its successfully running without Proguard settings.

I have learn to give Proguard Settings for [Google Place API](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Proguard) but when i set proguard like following just getting **NULL** in `status` of Place.

My Proguard Settings is:

```
-keep class android.support.v4.** {*;}
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**

-keep class com.google.** {*;}
-keep class com.slidingmenu.** {*;}
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** {*;}
-keep class com.ipaulpro.** {*;}
-keep class com.ianhanniballake.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.**

-dontwarn com.google.**
-dontwarn com.androidquery.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn com.ianhanniballake.**
-dontwarn com.ipaulpro.**

-libraryjars /libs/google-api-client-1.10.3-beta.jar
-libraryjars /libs/google-api-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar
-libraryjars /libs/google-http-client-1.10.3-beta.jar
-libraryjars /libs/google-http-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar
-libraryjars /libs/google-oauth-client-1.10.1-beta.jar
-libraryjars /libs/guava-11.0.1.jar
-libraryjars /libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar
-libraryjars /libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
-libraryjars /libs/protobuf-java-2.2.0.jar
-libraryjars /libs/maps.jar
-libraryjars /libs/httpclient-4.3.3.jar
-libraryjars /libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar
-libraryjars /libs/httpmime-4.3.3.jar
```

It is just not working when i set Proguard.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend checking out the example proguard settings here: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html

Remember to uncomment the following line in the project.properties file: //proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt

You might also want to double check the file paths for your -libraryjars depending on whether you want them to be absolute or local.